# How to display tkinter polygons on canvas under 3D conditions?

Tags: python, tkinter, 3d, render

I'm trying to create a program that renders an object in 3D and that you can rotate and control with your mouse's position. I'm trying to display the faces of the object but I don't know how could I display the closer faces first so that there isn't any 'background' face displayed in front of closer faces.

the code I provided is fully reproducable, just copy and paste it if you have tkinter and numpy.

```
from numpy import *
from tkinter import *

#eulers angles matrixes
def Rx(theta):
    return mat(mat([[1,     0     ,     0      ],
                    [0, cos(theta), -sin(theta)],
                    [0, sin(theta), cos(theta) ]]).round(15))

def Ry(theta):
    return mat(mat([[cos(theta), 0, -sin(theta)],
                    [    0     , 1,     0      ],
                    [sin(theta), 0, cos(theta) ]]).round(15))

def Rz(theta):
    return mat(mat([[cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0],
                    [sin(theta), cos(theta) , 0],
                    [    0     ,     0      , 1]]).round(15))
#returns a 2d projection matrix, 
def proj2d(p):
    return mat(eye(2,3)*p)

#tuple into vector
def vector(tuple):
    return transpose(mat(list(tuple)))

#updates position of the  3D point in function of the x,y,z angles
def position(pts3d,anglex,angley,anglez):
    for i in range(len(pts3d)):
        pts3d[i] = (float((Rx(anglex) * vector(pts3d[i]))[0]),
                    float((Rx(anglex) * vector(pts3d[i]))[1]),
                    float((Rx(anglex) * vector(pts3d[i]))[2]))
        pts3d[i] = (float((Ry(angley) * vector(pts3d[i]))[0]),
                    float((Ry(angley) * vector(pts3d[i]))[1]),
                    float((Ry(angley) * vector(pts3d[i]))[2]))
        pts3d[i] = (float((Rz(anglez) * vector(pts3d[i]))[0]),
                    float((Rz(anglez) * vector(pts3d[i]))[1]),
                    float((Rz(anglez) * vector(pts3d[i]))[2]))

#makes a projection of the 3d points on the 2d screen
def projected(pts3d):
    pts2d = []
    for i in pts3d:
        pts2d.append((float((proj2d(30+0.75*i[2]) * vector(i))[0]),
                      float((proj2d(30+0.75*i[2]) * vector(i))[1])))
    return pts2d

#displays dots
def dots(canvas,points):
    for i in points:
        canvas.create_oval(H/2+5+i[0],H/2+5+i[1],H/2-5+i[0],H/2-5+i[1],fill = 'white')

#displays vertices
def connect(canvas,vertics,points):
    for i in vertics:
        canvas.create_line(H/2+points[int(i[0])][0],H/2+points[int(i[0])][1],H/2+points[int(i[1])][0],H/2+points[int(i[1])][1],width = 2,fill = 'white')

#what I should modify, I guess: it's the funtion that displays the faces of the object
def face(canvas,faces,points,colors):
    for i in range(len(faces)):
        coordsface = ()
        for j in faces[i]:
            coordsface += (H/2+points[int(j)][0],H/2+points[int(j)][1])
        canvas.create_polygon(coordsface,fill = colors[i])

#major functions, updates position each time interval(delay)
def updateposition(self,H,canvas,points,vertics,faces,clrfc,delai,domegax,domegay,domegaz):
    canvas.delete('all')
    y,x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.winfo_rootx() - H/2, self.winfo_pointery() - self.winfo_rooty() - H/2
    if abs(x) >= H/2 or abs(y) >= H/2: x,y = 0,0
    domegax -= 0.00001*(x)
    domegay -= 0.00001*(y)
    position(points,domegax,domegay,domegaz)
    if affpts == 'y':
        dots(canvas,projected(points))
    if affart == 'y':
        connect(canvas,vertics,projected(points))
    if afffac == 'y':
        face(canvas,faces,projected(points),clrfc)
    self.after(delai,updateposition,self,H,canvas,points,vertics,faces,clrfc,delai,domegax,domegay,domegaz)

## cube

def pts3Dcube():
    #points
    a = ( L/2, L/2, L/2)
    b = ( L/2, L/2,-L/2)
    c = ( L/2,-L/2, L/2)
    d = ( L/2,-L/2,-L/2)
    e = (-L/2, L/2, L/2)
    f = (-L/2, L/2,-L/2)
    g = (-L/2,-L/2, L/2)
    h = (-L/2,-L/2,-L/2)
    pts3d = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
    #vertices
    aretes = []
    for i in [0,2,4,6]:
        aretes.append(str(i)+str(i+1))
    for i in [0,1,4,5]:
        aretes.append(str(i)+str(i+2))
    for i in [0,1,2,3]:
        aretes.append(str(i)+str(i+4))
    #faces
    faces = ['0132','4576','0154','2376','1375','0264']
    clrfc = ['green','red','yellow','blue','orange','white']
    return pts3d, aretes, faces, clrfc

## initial conditions
L = 5
H = 600
delai = 5

self = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(self,height = H,width = H,bg = 'gray13')
canvas.pack()

objet = pts3Dcube() #object choice

domegax = 0.0
domegay = 0.0
domegaz = 0.0

#initial rotation angles
iomegax = 0
iomegay = 0
iomegaz = 0

#displaying points, vertices, faces or not
affpts = 'y'
affart = 'y'
afffac = 'y'

position(objet[0],iomegax,iomegay,iomegaz) #initial rotation
updateposition(self,H,canvas,objet[0],objet[1],objet[2],objet[3],delai,domegax,domegay,domegaz) # dynamic rotation
```

if any of you have an idea, please comment it or something, I'm lost.
Thanks!

Comment: One solution would be to calculate the Z axis of each plane and then render the closest first.

Comment: I mean then render the closest at the end not first!

Comment: Nice, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Worked like a charm! after hours spent on reorganizing all the code.. I wonder how didn't I thought of this before, Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad could help you. Years ago I builded something similar: a rotating cube in all 3 axis and I was at the same situation like you and I also bang my had to come up with this solution. But be aware this solution has some drawbacks one of them will be when your planes overlap each other this algorithm will not work!